# Inflight CA certificate in mutual TLS authentication

Tags: ssl, mqtt

Recently I was debugging a mutual TLS issue between a MQTT client and a broker.
For the TLS setup, a self-signed CA was used to sign both server certificates and client certificates.

Both server and client trust stores had the CA certificate present.

During the handshake I observed, both brokers (RabbitMQ and Mosquitto) sent the CA certificate along with the server certificate.

But on clients, except for JAVA(PAHO), the Python and the nodejs clients both were also sending the CA certificate they had with their response to the server.

If the CA certificates were already installed in the trust stores of both the server and client, why should they exchange the CA at all during the handshake?

PS: Also JAVA client was never sending the CA certificate in its response. In which case, if the server did not send the certificate the handshake failed, but for other clients even if the server did not send the CA in the handshake, the clients were sending the CA in their response and the handshakes were successful.

Comment: All of the TLS certificate exchange happens before any of the MQTT connection starts so should be the same for any protocol. This question may be better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com (where this q+a may also help https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93157/in-ssl-server-handshake-does-server-also-send-ca-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

In general the root CA certificate don't need to be sent inside the TLS handshake, no matter if for client or server certificate. Trust anchors (i.e. the root certificate as the base of the trust chain) need to be already trusted by the peer and thus cannot be taken from a still untrusted network connection. If root CA is sent anyway it will be simply ignored.

Comment: "..still untrusted network connection" exactly my thoughts. But this is what I'm seeing in this specific scenario. Also, the client's implementation between different languages also differs from what I observed.

Comment: @NowaConcordia: If the client relies for trust solely on what was sent by the server the client is clearly wrong and insecure. If a root CA is sent it is wrong, but not insecure. Unfortunately one can only rely on your interpretation of what you saw, so it might still be possible that you misinterpret what you see.

Comment: I agree. It might not be insecure as implied in my observation. I'm planning to raise this to vendors of the software for clarification.